# how to delete from these jira tables

Tags: jira

Could someone, please, tell me how to delete from the following tables:
OS_HISTORYSTEP
OS_HISTORYSTEP_PREV
OS_CURRENTSTEP
OS_CURRENTSTEP_PREV
OS_WFENTRY

I have a jiraissue's ID that I need to remove. Can I find associated records in these tables to delete as well?

Comment: 99% of the time, the rule about removing items from the above tables is: *don't do it* and use a supported JIRA API instead (either Java or REST). Can you explain why you want to remove this data from these tables and why the APIs won't do it for you?

Comment: I understand that this way is not supported. I want to reduce the size of my d/b as it grows pretty rapidly. How would you use API to remove records from all these tables (or all tables) if all you have is data from jiraissue?

Comment: Why are you targeting these tables in specific? They generally contain status/workflow transition information for issues and I suspect you will be able to gain much more disk space by targeting other things (ie. attachments on the filesystem). Trying to partially trim these workflow transition tables could easily create problems for you later if JIRA expects to be able to find something that was removed. (But no, I'm not aware of any APIs to partially remove issue history information.)

Answer (score 0):

Jira issue associated on JIRAISSUE.WORKFLOW_ID=OS_WFENTRY.ID

but inaccurate actions on this table easily lead you to inoperable Jira

Comment: thank you for the update. what would be an example of inaccurate action? isn't it, just like you mentioned, JIRAISSUE.WORKFLOW_ID=OS_WFENTRY.ID ?